# In pytorch, it is still possible to train without adding model parameters to the optimizer

Tags: python, pytorch

As far as I know, the parameters of the model are not trainable without putting them into the optimizer. But recently when I was running a project on github, I found that the model parameters can be trained without putting them into the optimizer. The code address of this project to add parameters to the optimizer is https://github.com/zjunlp/HVPNeT/blob/main/modules/train.py#L500.

```py
    def multiModal_before_train(self):
        # bert lr
        parameters = []
        params = {'lr':self.args.lr, 'weight_decay':1e-2}
        params['params'] = []
        for name, param in self.model.named_parameters():
            if 'bert' in name:
                params['params'].append(param)
        parameters.append(params)

        # prompt lr
        params = {'lr':self.args.lr, 'weight_decay':1e-2}
        params['params'] = []
        for name, param in self.model.named_parameters():
            if 'encoder_conv' in name or 'gates' in name:
                params['params'].append(param)
        parameters.append(params)

        # crf lr
        params = {'lr':5e-2, 'weight_decay':1e-2}
        params['params'] = []
        for name, param in self.model.named_parameters():
            if 'crf' in name or name.startswith('fc'):
                params['params'].append(param)

        self.optimizer = optim.AdamW(parameters)

        for name, par in self.model.named_parameters(): # freeze resnet
            if 'image_model' in name:   par.requires_grad = False

        self.scheduler = get_linear_schedule_with_warmup(optimizer=self.optimizer, 
                                                            num_warmup_steps=self.args.warmup_ratio*self.train_num_steps, 
                                                            num_training_steps=self.train_num_steps)
        self.model.to(self.args.device)
```

It can be found that the parameters of crf and fc are added to params, but not to parameters. But they can still be trained, does anyone know why?

Answer (score 0):

The model is based on prompt learning, and it is possible to train classifiers without training if prompts are trained.

Comment: Please consider providing link to resources or additional documentation to support your answer.